# Install superfish menu in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I need to use [superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) in my site built upon Drupal 7, I installed libraries and superfish modules and enabled them. Also I installed superfish library and everything went OK.

Also, I have added a new region named "superfish_menu" into `mytheme.info`.

Then go to blocks and assigned superfish 1 block to superfish_menu region then configure the block to assigned main menu in this block.

then go to page.tpl.php and put this code

```
 <div style="border:3px solid red">
   <?php print render($page['superfish_menu']); ?>
 </div>
```

Finally, I cleared the cache. but unfortunately I can not see the superfish menu.

What I missed to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that parent menu items are `Marked as expanded`. You can find that in menu item edit page, just make sure this checkbox is checked.

Also check if you have downloaded the superFish library : https://github.com/mehrpadin/Superfish-for-Drupal/zipball/master

Comment: i made sure the parent items marked as expanded. the issue is no menu appeared.

Comment: Is it a mutli-lingual website ?

Comment: Looks like u have done everything right. Try to make sure if the menu markup is being printed in the web page.

Comment: Use the browser dom inspector or firebug to find if the markup is delivered to the web page.

Comment: i did that, the div is empty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22341/discussion-between-ayman-hussein-and-muhammad-reda)